# Javascript regular expressions to remove character from a strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove all occurrences of the words "hello" and "-hello" in a string, the "-" in "-hello" is a minus sign.

I am currently doing it as such

```js
let regex = /hello/-hello/g

let word = "Hello, How are -hello you doing"

let newWord = word.replace(regex,'')
```

But this seems to throw an error, what is that correct way to do this?

thank you

Comment: Try `regex = /-?\bhello\b/g`

Comment: Or `regex = /(-?hello)/gi`

Comment: The error is thrown because you're using `/` instead of `|`. The `/` after *hello* closes the regex literal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
    let regex =  /-?hello/gi;
    
    let word = "Hello, How are -hello you doing"
    
    let newWord = word.replace(regex,'')
    
    console.log(newWord);
```

Comment: This will remove `hello` in `chello` or `hellois`